# How to switch test provider from MSAA to UIA in custom control for VS Coded UI Test Builder

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am implementing automation providers for some 3-rd party controls, so I can test my application's UI with VS coded ui tests. I am using UI Automation approach for doing this. In standard inspect tools they looked fine, but when I used VS coded UI test builder, all my controls are treated as MSAA in technology name (instead of UIA), so most of my properties are missed. What should I do, so VS Coded UI treated it as UIA?
Here is my code for returning automation provider:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ControlWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) 
    {
    case WM_GETOBJECT:
        {
            // If the lParam matches the RootObjectId, send back the RawElementProvider
            if (static_cast<long>(lParam) == static_cast<long>(UiaRootObjectId))
            {
                CustomButton* pControl = reinterpret_cast<CustomButton*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
                IRawElementProviderSimple* pRootProvider = pControl->GetUIAutomationProvider();
                return UiaReturnRawElementProvider(hwnd, wParam, lParam, pRootProvider);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    ...
}
```

This code is called when I used complex automation tool such Ranorex or simply Inspect.exe with UIA mode. But with VS there was no any UiaRootObjectId request.
Instead it call this with `lParam == OBJID_CLIENT` param. So it returns some default MSAA provider.

[UI Control Map snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3w6h.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case that someone stuck with the same problem, here is a solution I've found. You should create your custom server-side provider, which will be used for your controls class name (it should be VS plugin .dll or something like this).

Your custom provider .dll should be placed to your visual studio directory, after that all your controls in VS coded ui plugin will have technology name, fields and roles that you have described by itself. Example for custom provider can be found on msdn and other resources